# Angular - Display grid of images that take up entire screen

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I have an Angular SPA with bootstrap. There I have an overview page that shows a list of "campaigns" and am struggling with how to implement the design on desktop.

Campaigns have background images, which I want to display (they also have names that I'd also want to display, but for simplification purpose let's leave those out for now). I'm trying to build a reactive desktop design that properly splits the screen into squares, one for each campaign and containing the campaign's background image. The desktop design is supposed to make use of 100% of the screen space.

The requirements I have on the design for desktop are

- No free space is supposed to be visible, 100% of the screen-space is supposed to be taken up by background images to click on.
- One row of campaigns is supposed to contain at most 3 entries
- One page of campaigns is supposed to contain at most 3 rows
- If a row contains less than the maximum number of entries, the rest of the entries are supposed to expand in width to make use of the free space
- If a page contains less than the maximum number of rows, the other rows are supposed to expand in height to make use of the free space
- If the mouse hovers over an image, it is supposed to light up

I am able to create such a grid, but not quite how I want. To display the background-image of a campaign, I can either:

1. use `<img src="{{campaign.backgroundImage}}">` tags, or
2. set the background image of the surrounding div like this `<div [style.background-image]="'url('+campaign.backgroundImage+')"></div>`.

If I do 1), the images don't play nice with my grid system, no matter what I try. They somehow lead to expanding columns leading to rows of unequal height and columns within a row that are not equally large. A demonstration of that [here in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vyvuv6?file=src/app/app.component.html)

If I do 2) I don't see how I can have a highlighting effect on hover.

How can I solve this properly?

```
//The HTML for solution based on 1)
<div class="container d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row h-100" *ngFor="let dataRow of processedData">
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let dataPoint of dataRow">
      <img src="{{dataPoint}}" alt="an image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean, something like this? https://angular-ivy-5fsjcw.stackblitz.io

Comment: @JacekRatajewski That would be approach number 2), how would you best apply some sort of highlighting effect when hovering over these images? What I would normally have done was drop the opacity on the image to 0.5 (while having a black background) and set it to 1 when hovering over it, but I don't think that's possible when setting the image as the `background-image` property. I could apply that approach by changing the opacity of the entire div, but then any text within that div would also be affected, not just the div with the background image.

Comment: Hmm i don't think its impossible, look at example one more time, i changed it for you. Now it has `background-color: black` and background as an image, with opacity, and opacity on hover.

Comment: optionally if that's not what you are looking for, you can make use of ::before and ::after pseudo-elements. Setting one of them as black background of div, it requires a little bit of knowing how to use position and z-index, but its not rocket science :)

Comment: @JacekRatajewski I just went over your example again and I finally realized that you aren't achieving this through display flex and setting widths or any sort of flex property, but by using some sort of grid autofit property! That's brilliant! I hadn't even been aware those existed! Sadly it means I won't be using bootstrap css classes, but I think I can live with having a custom solution on a single page. Could you give a link to look at the entire project and not just the finished HTML?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5fsjcw Here you go